# Moment generating function of $Z=X-Y$ where $X,Y$ are independent binomial RVs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, binomial-distribution, moment-generating-functions

$X$ and $Y$ are statistically independent random variables.

- $X\sim \text{Bin}(n_1,p_1)$
- $Y\sim \text{Bin}(n_2,p_2)$
- $Z = X -Y$
- $q_1 = 1 - p_1$
- $q_2 = 1 - p_2$

I am trying to find the moment-generating function $ \phi_z(\omega)$.
At this point I got to $(q_1 + p_{1}\cdot e^{\omega})^{n_{1}} \cdot (q_2 + p_2\cdot e^{-\omega})^{n_{2}}$

Is this the correct moment generating function?
Attached are my notes about how I got to this result.
[Notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e9yWRl7nO-ycvuFymJrz_PGyRpixLAH-/view)

Comment: That is correct.